# Cypher UNWIND'ing and applying multiple labels to a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For a case I need to create nodes and apply defined labels to that node. The definition of nodes and labels are stored in an Excel sheet which I transform in Python with the help of pandas.

Now, I have the following code that unwinds the labels, but the problem is that the resulting node gets the literal label name 'label'.

Is there a way to apply labels to a node with an unwind?

```
WITH s, row
FOREACH (label in row.labels |
    SET s :label)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set dynamic labels in Cypher alone, however there's an [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) procedure for that, [`apoc.create.addLabels()`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data). It even takes a list, so you don't have to `UNWIND`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!